# Get error messages from gnome-shell

Tags: session, gnome-shell

I want to run gnome-shell on my PC. I have Ubuntu and gnome-shell is installed from ppa.

When I run:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

the session fails - I am on the GDM login screen and can't get any error messages.

If I use the command:

```
gnome-shell --verbose --replace > gnomeshell.log
```

gives me an empty file.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the log files gnome-shell produces.

Comment: Hi, it would have been better to specify which log files these are.

Comment: There are many and these change between versions. It is better to look in the typical locations a Linux user would expect them to be or consult the documentation if the developers have preferred to use non-standard locations.